# preventDefault works great, but there is a console error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, actioncable

preventDefault works great, but there is a console error

I'm building a messaging app which uses Rails, Actionacable, Turbolinks, and jQuery

The problem (because of Turbolinks):

Chat is working great, however, each time I navigate away from the chatroom and back, any subsequent new message will appear multiple times.

Anyhow, I finally managed to solve  the problem with PreventDefault():

```
//room_channel.js//

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {

consumer.subscriptions.create({ channel: "RoomChannel", room_id: room_id }, {
...
...
received(data) {
  let messages
  messages = $("#messages_" + data.project_id);
  messages.append(data.message);
  messages.preventDefault()
```

it works and there is no message duplication but console log says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: messages.preventDefault is not a function
```

I tried to put `$('#new_message').on('click', function(e){ .... or // submit(function...,etc..`

but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? [`Event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) is a function to prevent the default event handler for events - `messages` is just a jQuery object. Its not going to do anything to stop you from appending the same response to the DOM over and over.

Comment: I'm not js expert. but when I added Event.preventDefault, messages works and not duplicated with tubolinks, but it keeps showing the console log